# re.sub() on dataframe using list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-re

I have a dataframe with a `manufacturer_part_number` column. I'm trying to run the following list comprehension on it:

```
x = [(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d]', '', row)) for row in df_1['manufacturer_part_number']]
```

I keep getting this error:

```
x = [(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d]', '', row)) for row in df_1['manufacturer_part_number']]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-5af324f72742>", line 1, in <module>
    x = [(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d]', '', row)) for row in df_1['manufacturer_part_number']]

  File "<ipython-input-3-5af324f72742>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    x = [(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\d]', '', row)) for row in df_1['manufacturer_part_number']]

  File "C:\Program-Files\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I added `df_1['manufacturer_part_number'].astype(str)` before trying it and it still failed.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine on toy example data. Can you provide a (small) sample dataframe that reproduces this error, so that you have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ok, I think there's a problematic entry in the dataset. I ran the code on the first 10 observations and it worked. There must be some freak value way down in the dataset. Thanks Crazy for point me in the right direction.

Comment: On another note, regardless of what's causing this error for you, you'd probably get better performance using Panda's own [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) than iterating over the series with a list comprehension.